# Uninitialized constant Supplier::Categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, project

My problem is that I try to invoke an association to a table. I get the ID number but want to get a different field from it. when will this problem up
Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :suppliers
```

end
   class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :categories
   end

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :categories
 end
```

Controller

```
def index
 @suppliers = Supplier.all
end
View :
 <% @suppliers.each do |s|%> 
                <td><%= s.name %></td>
                <td><%= s.inspect %></td>
                <% s.categories.each do |c|%> 
                    <td><%= c.inspect %></td>
                    <%end%>
                <% end %>


errormesseage : uninitialized constant Supplier::Categories
```

Comment: Where is the foreign key on your model? Does the `Supplier` have a `category_id` or does the `Category` have a `supplier_id`?

Comment: It is categories_id. I do want a "supplier" to a category such as "bread-provider" but may only be out categories_id @Gareth

Comment: You're defining a one to many relationship where a supplier has one category, but your controller suggests that either you want it the other way around, or you want a `has_and_belongs_to_many`, so that suppliers can have many categories and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your supplier model should have a `category_id` field (singular), *not* a `categories_id` field (plural).

Once you've done that, change your model to

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :categories
end
```

and everything will start working.

If English is not your first language it might not be obvious, but Rails tries to stick to English linguistic conventions. So, because a supplier only belongs to a single category, you use the singular form when talking about the relationship.

This is the same logic that means your class is [a single] `Supplier` but the database table contains `suppliers`

Comment: You will also in my migrations-file at from t.references :categories  to t.references :category ?

Comment: Yes. Because each supplier references a single category

Comment: if i change : undefined method `categories' for #<Supplier:0x37ee5c8>

Comment: Right, for the same reason. A supplier has a single category, so your call should be `@supplier.category`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have category_id column in your suppliers table then you should declare the belongs_to association as below.

```
class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
  #not
  #belongs_to :categories
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Comment: Nej, om jag skriver kontrollera enligt min mening.

#<Supplier id: 1, name: "Ica Maxi", city: "Stockholm", Contactperson: "Kalle svensson", Phonenumber: "4564564", categories_id: 1, created_at: "2012-05-13 11:31:42", updated_at: "2012-05-13 11:31:42">

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798253/getting-uninitialized-constant-error-when-using-delegate-in-belongs-to-in-mode

Comment: Visit http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Associations#belongs_to

Comment: Try belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => "categories_id"